# Get android system key repeat time

Tags: java, android, view, keyevent

Inside my custom view class I am using `Overscroller` class to scroll it when user touches the screen. It works great, and now I want my view to be able to scroll when I press arrows keys and to do this this I use `overscroller.startScroll(startX,startY, distX,distY, duration)`, but in order to animate the scroll correctly when user holds the key I have to know the delay in millisecond between keys repeating.
As it is managed by android system, I think there should a way to get this value ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.